# How to pass to image buffer to wasm

Tags: c++, opencv, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to pass array buffer js to wasm OpenCV but some times It throws an exception or some time blank array when using imdecode function.
**Simple HTML:**

`<input type='file' id accept='image/*' onchange='openFile(event)'>`

**Javascript code**

```
 var openFile = function (e) {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = (event) => {
                const uint8Arr = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
                passToWasm(uint8Arr);
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
        };

   function passToWasm(uint8ArrData) {
            // copying the uint8ArrData to the heap
            const numBytes = uint8ArrData.length * uint8ArrData.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;
            const dataPtr = Module._malloc(numBytes);
            const dataOnHeap = new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, dataPtr, numBytes);
            dataOnHeap.set(uint8ArrData);
            // calling the Wasm function
            const res = Module._image_input(dataOnHeap.byteOffset, uint8ArrData.length);
        }
```

**C++ code:**

```
extern "C"
{
   int image_input(uint8_t* buffer, size_t nSize) //query image input
    {
        Mat raw_data = cv::Mat(1, nSize, CV_8UC1, buffer);
        img_object = cv::imdecode(raw_data, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED);
        cout << img_object << endl;
        return 1
    }
}
```

Please help me I have spent many days to solve this problem.
I'm trying the same with the help of the following question.

[How to pass image frames camera to a function in wasm (C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845033/how-to-pass-image-frames-camera-to-a-function-in-wasm-c)

Answer (score 0):

`malloc()` and `HEAP8.set()` can be used to achieve that. [Surma's article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/emscripting-a-c-library) describes how to do this indetail.  Another example is this [`decode()`](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/src/emscripten-post.js#L75) function, which sets values in Wasm from a JavaScript ArrayBuffer.